# como colocar una fila entre ejecucion ngFor?

Tags: angular

Mi objetivo es que dependiendo de un cambio en el Pipe que uso para ordenar los valores en mi vista poder colocar una fila donde colocare un total, con este pipe logro ordenar la data:

```
  transform(value: any[], order = '', column: string = ''): any[] {    
    if (!value || order === '' || !order) { return value; } // no array

    if (value.length <= 1) { return value; } // array with only one item

    if (!column || column === '') { 
      if(order==='asc'){return value.sort()}
      else{return value.sort().reverse();}
    } // sort 1d array

    return orderBy(value, [column], [order]);
  }
```

y lo uso asi:

```
<tr *ngFor="let producto of productos | orderby:'asc':'Department' | groupsum">
```

Visualmente se ve asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero lo que quiero es que cuando la data en la columna 'Marca' cambie aparesca una fila diferente donde mas adelante colocare el total por marcas, el resultado final que busco es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que la columna 'activity' te refieres a las 'marcas' y que están ordenadas.

puedes preguntar si hay siguiente producto y si este es de la misma 'activity'

```
    <tr *ngFor="let producto of productos | orderby:'asc':'Department' | groupsum; index as i ">
<!-- pintado de las cosas, los tags usados a continuación no son lo relevante, son para comprensión del sitio -->



  <!-- casos para mostrar un total:
- si es el ultimo producto
ò
-no es el primero y si el anterior producto tiene una marca distinta
-->
<div *ngIf="productos.length - 1 == i || i != 0 && productos[i-1].marca != producto.marca">

<span> {{ total(producto.marca) }}</span>

</div>
```

.TS

```
// aquí, con el nombre conseguiremos la cantidad de veces que encuentra
        total(marcaNombre){
 const total =  this.productos.filter( producto => producto.marca == marcaNombre);
return ('Totales': total.lenght)
    }
```